# Can an upgrade of Ubuntu server break a python application?

Tags: ubuntu

Recently a proposal for upgrade was made for my server.

I have a Python application on it. So before proceeding I wanted to know if there is a risk that interferences with my application appear, which would require me to redo some installations.

As the application is in production then I need to avoid any manipulation that would put the application out of production for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Test your application in your test environment, same as production but distinct and upgraded first. Now would be a good time to create such an environment if it does not exist yet.

A newer Python, or keeping the same Python, has never been easier to test with lightweight virtualenvs and/or containers.

Also test how you will upgrade and manage the host OS, whether VM or bare metal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. The likely cause of a failure is replacement of python with a newer version that introduces incompatibilities - whether or not this haapens depends on your code, python versions, distro and method of installing python in the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

So, OS upgrade is not gives assurance for applications, if you are using any application which is version dependent to any lib or programming language best is to do test before doing on production. New OS may have too many changes in libraries including python or other programming language changes and if your application code is not compatible application will not work or misbehave.